# Should you remove a GameComponent from Game.Components in it's destructor?

Tags: xna, components

Say you have created an instance of some GameComponent subclass and used `Game.Components.Add(component)` so that its Initialize and Update functions will be called by the framework. Now if component goes out of scope and has no existing references besides the Game.Components list, will it continue to be updated until I call `Game.Component.Remove(component)`, or is it removed automatically?

In other words, when is the proper time and what is the proper way to remove a component from Game.Components?

Comment: Component.Remove is the right way to remove a component.

But make sure the component isn't doing anything anymore.

Comment: An object's destructor won't be invoked until the object is collected (and there is no guarantee that it will be invoked, ever).  An object won't be collected while there are living references to it.  Therefore, a component's destructor won't be invoked until after it has been removed from the components list, if it is ever invoked at all.  So no, the destructor is not the right place to put it.  Most C# classes shouldn't have destructors; only use them if you have native resources that need to be released.